# Use Microsoft BotBuilder framework with service account possible?

Tags: botframework

Is there a way wo authenticate at AADv2 with an service account? The service account should be added to the .bot file and encrypted as example.

It is needed because the bot has to use different Graph api and SharePoint features where not all users are have permissions on it. It is also for me not the best way that a user has to login in Teams again after he is logged in to teams ...

So I‘am looking for a way to get data from the graph api e.g. calendar data from alle meeting participants without requesting the users to authenticate. The service account should have admin rights and can access all data over graph api within the company.

BR

Comment: Are you using Node.js or .NET?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you mean by service account?

Comment: Added details for your question